# How to get rid of the white rectangle flashing that occurs during Java applet loading?

Tags: java, browser, applet

While an applet is loading, it displays a white rectangle for a split second. How can we get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting Java 6 you can try the new plugin options for displaying a loading screen. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/plugin2-142482.html#LOADING_SCREEN

Comment: My applet is a public game and needs to work with older jvms too.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try loading your applet offscreen?

You can then use MAYSCRIPT+LiveConnect to have your applet signal that it is running and have JavaScript move the applet container back onscreen.

Comment: I guess this white rectangle appears during the time in which browser fetch the class file from server. JDK6 has support for showing images during this time. But I have to support old jvms too.